# Visualforce.remoting.Manager in a Static Resource used in a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-remoting

I am trying to convert a Visualforce page into a Lightning Component. The Visualforce page uses jQuery code in a static resource to insert HTML it generates based on a `VisualForce.remoting.Manager` call in the static resource. I have gotten everything to load properly and even insert placeholder HTML into the Lightning Component but when it gets to the actual Visualforce.remoting.Manager call it throws an error saying: `TypeError: Visualforce is undefined`.

Do I need to do something to allow the static resource to call the `VisualForce.remoting.Manager` or is it just not allowed in the Lightning Component and I have to instead do the call directly to the apex in the Lightning Component Controller.js file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use Javascript Remoting for lightning components .You will have to annotate your methods with @AuraEnabled and the invocation mechanism for both differ widely .

**For Javascript Remoting on Visualforce the invocation mechanism is as below**

```
<apex:page controller="AccountRemoter">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRemoteAccount() {
    var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
        accountName, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this

            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

            } else {

            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
}
</script>
```

**For Lightning components you invoke an AuraEnabled class as below**

```
({
"echo" : function(cmp) {
    // create a one-time use instance of the serverEcho action
    // in the server-side controller
    var action = cmp.get("c.getAccount");
    action.setParams({ accountName : cmp.get("v.firstName") });

    // Create a callback that is executed after 
    // the server-side action returns
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        // This callback doesn’t reference cmp. If it did,
        // you should run an isValid() check
        //if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // Alert the user with the value returned 
            // from the server
            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());

            // You would typically fire a event here to trigger 
            // client-side notification that the server-side 
            // action is complete
        }
        //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "INCOMPLETE") {
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
        //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "ERROR") {
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });

    // optionally set storable, abortable, background flag here

    // A client-side action could cause multiple events, 
    // which could trigger other events and 
    // other server-side action calls.
    // $A.enqueueAction adds the server-side action to the queue.
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
   }
 })
```

Its worth noting couple of differences

1.The backend apex can be same except its annotated differently in both case .Uses @RemoteAction for vf and @Auraenabled for lightning components

2.For lightning components every property needs to be annotated with @auraenabled for the variable to reflect in UI